# ARE MOVING vs MOVE

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the diffence between the following sentences in meaning: 1) Ears sweep a liquid in your inner ears when YOU ARE MOVING
2) Ears sweep a liquid in your inner ear when YOU MOVE.

Answer (score 1):

The first version doesn't necessarily imply that the moving is being actively done by you: you could be in a rollercoaster or a swing, for example. The second does imply that it is you moving by your own effort.

Note though that "Ears sweep a liquid" doesn't seem to make sense.